# OKTA application report

Tags: report, okta, policy

I need your help. I'm new to the Okta world, and I have a question: how can I pull the report from Okta of those applications that are using sign-on policies for their apps? How can I pull the report in an Excel sheet for those apps? Please help me on this issue.

Thanks

I'm new to this tool so i have no idea.